# Include and _SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Tags: php

I have 2 pages. file2.php is generating links, depending on which page you are on the website.

file1.html

```
<!--#include virtual="file2.php" -->
<a href="<?php echo $link ?>">Link</a>
```

file2.php

```
$q = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (preg_match('/\bSOMETHING\b/i', $q)) {
    $link = "whateverpage.php";
    //...
```

My problem is that on my dev server, I'm getting $q=file1.html but on my live server, $q=file2.php. Any idea why I'm getting 2 differents values?

Comment: What does `<!--#include virtual="file2.php" -->` do?

Comment: I see it's a [server side include](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html). You should mention that.

Comment: Yes, file1.html include file2.php.

Comment: Why are you using SSI and not just 2 PHP files with a [php include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)?

Comment: If it was just me, I would have used 2 php file, but I can't. My boss don't want too (Don't ask me why...)

Answer (score 0):

If the files, paths, etc are exactly alike, you might compare the results of phpinfo(); on each machine.

Comment: I tought about that. The dev is running 5.2.9 and the live is running 5.2.9-20090427. Any big difference between those two version? And which output should I normally expect?

Comment: I'm not sure of the differences, but your dev should always mirror production unless you're testing an update to a newer version of a component.